# Writing a code template for Eclipse PDT with context=php_new_file_context

Tags: xml, eclipse, templates, eclipse-pdt

I have a basic class that I extend fairly often.  I thought it would be nice to add a template of the extension as a choice when creating a new file.  I went to Eclipse->Preferences->PHP->Code Style->Code Templates and decided to copy and modify the "Simple php file".  So I exported that template and opened it up.  It looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<templates>
    <template autoinsert="true" context="php_new_file_context"
        deleted="false" description="Simple php file" enabled="true"
        id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.author" name="New simple PHP file">
    &lt;?php
            ${cursor}
    ?&gt;
    </template>
</templates>
```

I edited the file to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<templates>
    <template autoinsert="true" context="php_new_file_context"
        deleted="false" description="PHP Item subclass file" enabled="true"
        id="org.eclipse.php.ui.editor.templates.php.itemclass" name="Item subclass file">
        &lt;?php
        /**
        * ${enter description}
        * @author: My Name
        * @version: 
        **/
        class ${classname} extends Item {
            const PKEY='${pkey}'; //name of primary key variable
            const TABLE='${table}'; //name of db table

            //db table vars
            $${pkey};
            $${name};

            //history vars


            public static function who() {
                return __CLASS__;
            }

        }
        ?&gt;
    </template>
</templates>
```

Then I saved it as item.xml and tried to import it. The import threw no errors, but the new template didn't show up in the list. The only thing I can think is that the string I chose for the id attribute is problematic.  But I can't find any references on properly authoring a template. Either my google-fu is failing, or I'm trying to do something I'm not supposed to; I don't know.

Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have here is that there is an space in the name of a variable the third line of the template, `${enter description}` and this isn't allowed by eclipse, but those variables won't be considered for autofilling.

Even though, it'll not let you import them, because it's a feature that is no longer supported, as [stated in their bugtracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=318164#c6). You could use the current templating system, wich will let you add variables to autofill. To use it, you have to go to `PHP > Editor > Templates`. Then, you'd create a new template with wichever name you want, and when you started typing it on a new php file, if you'd select it from the auto-complete.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug.  I'd eventually come to do it as you suggested, but I thought it was a work-around rather than the new way to do things.  I hope they remove the possibility of doing things the old way soon; it just confuses things.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was wondering for ages why I couldn't add my own templates.

Comment: Those who would like to see this feature added back in, please vote on this bug report on eclipse's site.